# How to enable "always embed swift standard libraries" for a xamrin app?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin forms app, in which I am using a binding dll generated for a swift framework.

But as per apple doc,
If you are building an app that does not use Swift but embeds content such as a framework that does, Xcode will not include these libraries in your app. To workaround this issue, set the Embedded Content Contains Swift Code (EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT) build setting to YES in your app. This build setting, which specifies whether a target's product has embedded content with Swift code, tells Xcode to embed Swift standard libraries in your app when set to YES.

So how can we enable this build setting for a xamarin app ?

[Edit]
SwiftRuntimeSupport NuGet package is already part of the project. But still, on checking the ipa, it was found that the swiftSupport folder includes only an empty iphoneos folder.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin has a SwiftRuntimeSupport nuget that handles the iOS version and build details.

> Use the **SwiftRuntimeSupport** NuGet package to automatically include required dylib dependencies into the resulting application package.

[Consume the Xamarin binding library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/#consume-the-xamarin-binding-library)

Blog Post: [Binding iOS Swift Libraries](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/binding-ios-swift-libraries/)

Comment: I already have that NuGet package included in my project. The appstore rejected the app. Regenerated the ipa, unzipped and checked. The swiftSupport folder had an empty iphoneos folder.

Comment: @MidhunKumar If your app is targeting iOS 12.2 and Swift 5.1, then Swift is included in iOS as it now has a stable ABI, iOS versions and Swift versions below that, require that the Swift libraries be included in your app. The  SwiftRuntimeSupport nuget handles those versions requirements, what is your app targeting?

Comment: Deployment target is 10.0

Comment: Hi @MidhunKumar, Have you got any soution to this problem? Currently i am facing the same problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I got an error with using Swift libraries and I tried @SushiHangover's solution. While the library itself did not solve the problem, it had these instructions in the Readme file for uploading the Archive using XCode instead of Visual Studio, which solved my problem:

1. In Visual Studio, select a valid iOS device before archiving.
2. Go to *Build* menu / *Archive for Publishing*
3. Once done, open Xcode and go to *Window* / *Organizer*
4. Select the *Archives* tab
5. On the left side of the window, select your app
6. Click on *Distribute App* button and follow the wizard